# Visual Basic in VS 2013 and Excel 2010: cannot find xlQualityStandard (is not declared)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, ms-office, excel-2010

I am trying to code some Excel automation stuff using VB in VS2013. Basically, I can perform a lot of excel operation from my code (even applying the data analysis tool, and creating histograms).

However, in my case, Visual Studio is complaining 'xlQualityStandard' is not declared.

Here is a sample of my code

```
Imports Microsoft.Office
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

' do something
xlTempSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(Type:=Excel.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, Filename:="c:\plots test\test.pdf",
                                    IgnorePrintAreas:=True, OpenAfterPublish:=True, Quality:=xlQualityStandard)
```

If I remove

```
Quality:=xlQualityStandard
```

The code will just work.

Comment: Only thing I can suggest is to make sure the PDF add-in is installed properly. Also, double check the version of Interop and make sure it is for Office 2010. the Quality parameter for excel started with Excel 2010 so older versions won't have the parameter defined.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. By reading your comment, I actually found 'Excel.XlFixedFormatQuality.xlQualityStandard' will do the job. Thumb up. @user2930100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case,

```
Excel.XlFixedFormatQuality.xlQualityStandard
```

will work. Thanks to user2930100

Answer (score 1):

The values can be found here

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb241292(v=office.12).aspx

```
xlQualityMinimum    1   Minimum quality
xlQualityStandard   0   Standard quality
```

Interestingly Google now seems to [provide API help](https://www.google.ie/search?q=xlQualityStandard&oq=xlQualityStandard&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.175j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=xlQualityStandard%20value)